# really fast moving star-like light

Tags: star, light

I don't know ANYTHING about astronomy but I know what I saw and 2 of my siblings saw it too. I initially thought it was a shooting star, but a Google search quickly made it clear that it wasn't.
it was of similar brightness to the surrounding stars and weirdly wasn't moving in a single direction. it was moving erratically in no particular path, was not constrained to a specific area and almost mimicked what a laser point would look like if a human was moving it randomly. I do not believe satellites move at the speed at which it was moving and as randomly.. 
what could this possibly be?

Comment: Were you looking through a window or a pair of glasses?

Comment: @John Dvorak absolutely not. I wear contacts and besides  oth my siblings have 20/20 vision. we were on the roof

Comment: It might have been a star (or planet). Did it stay in roughly the same place, but just seem to bounce around. If so, look for a source of heat  (chimney or flue) directly below where it appeared to be.